# How to root Huawei mate 8

Tags: rooting, huawei

I just bought a Huawei Mate 8 two weeks ago and now I need to root it – as some of apps require root access or I can't use the app. I have tried towelroot and iroot, both didn't work. please help.

Comment: This thread May help http://forum.xda-developers.com/mate-8/general/rooting-mate-8-t3284455/page3

Comment: sorry, i can't understand chinese

Comment: Go here and download this tool. Follow the directions.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/mate-8/development/rayglobe-italian-knife-t3295526

Comment: You have to pay for the bootloader unlock code (4 euros). I don't recommend that solution. Please hold out a bit till a proper **free** root comes out.